# Querying urls from a database - back slashes being added into url

Tags: php, android, json

I'm querying a mysql database using phpand returning the result in json format to my android application. I have urls stored in my database in this format:

```
<img src="http://ec2-54-228-87-185.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/corkgaa/Matchprogrammes/sample1.bmp">
```

However, the url my android application is receiving is incorrect.

It seems to be putting back slashes infront of every front slash which is causing errors when I'm trying to use it in android.

My php script is:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nemo");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
    $output[]=$row;
 }

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close($con);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)
Thanks!

Comment: Why not use: [stripslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)? Like this: `$output[] = stripslashes($row);`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php is active ?

Comment: i dont think it has anything to do with magic quotes as I am running php 5.4.3  and with the strip slashes I am returning other strings other than the url which don't contain slashes, so I am getting an error when I put this into my php script

Comment: @360flowMichael `Magic Quotes` has been deprecated since PHP 5.3.0

Comment: @NullPointer I meant that it could be a problem if it were turn on on older php ver. Some hostings do that.